# .Net naming conventions vs W3C specifications

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

I'm having a hard time resolving a naming convention conflict I'm having with implementing part of the W3C HTML5 specification using .Net.

The issue is that I like to conform to standard .Net naming conventions, which use UpperCamelCasing, but the W3C specifications indicate that the naming conventions should use lowerCamelCasing.

Should I deviate from the specification in order to write code that is friendly and familiar to the .Net community, or should I use the W3C-recommended conventions in order to stick to the specification as closely as possible, even though this will make my Code.notVeryPretty()?

EDIT

Example:

The W3C defines an interface `IDOMImplementation` with a member `hasFeature()`. If I were writing .Net code without a W3C specification guiding the implementation, these would be named `IDomImplementation` and `HasFeature()`, but the W3C defines naming conventions as specified above.

EDIT

To ask this question a completely different way, is there any downside to deviating from the W3C-recommended casing conventions when implementating their specification using .Net?

Comment: I wasn't aware that W3C has .NET coding standards.

Comment: .NET and W3C have nothing to do with each other...

Comment: W3C does not have .Net coding standards. Microsoft (and the .Net community at large) do.

Comment: The W3C are not to be trusted. Anyone associated with the W3C is a joke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `UpperCamelCasing` for .NET code and `lowerCamelCasing` for your HTML/CSS/Javascript/other W3C stuff.

In what situation would you code .NET code using W3C recommended naming conventions?

**Edit:**

Now that you have clarified exactly what you mean, I would say that since your code is to be **consumed** within .NET, you should stick with .NET conventions, even when implementing an interface defined by W3C.

Comment: In other words, stick to the pure W3C spec where it is defined and use normal .Net naming conventions elsewhere? See my edit above for an example of what I was talking about.

Comment: Yeah. Make JavaScript look like it should and C# look like it should. They do indeed have different conventions, and it makes it easier for those used to both to follow the code.

Comment: JavaScript is a different matter and would probably be wrapped anyway to ensure that only appropriate functionality is exposed to the scripting engine.